# Nested loop with user and folder in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have the following task:

```yaml
- name: Create required folders.
  become: true
  ansible.builtin.file:
    owner: "{{ item.key }}"
    group: ftp
    mode: '0755'  
    path: '/data/{{ item.key }}/in'
    state: directory
  loop: "{{ query('dict', ftp) | list }}"
  when: "'state' not in item.value or item.value.state == 'present'"
```

And the following host variables with different users:

```yaml
ftp:
  test:
     ssh_public_key: "XXXX"
     password: "XXX" 
     home: /data/test
  test2:
     ssh_public_key: "XXXX"
     password: "XXX" 
     home: /data/test2
```

What I want is to create two directories for every user :

```yaml
path: '/data/{{ user }}/in' # item.key, in the code above
path: '/data/{{ user }}/out' # item.key, in the code above
```

But I already need the loop for iterating over the users itself:

```yaml
loop: "{{ query('dict', ftp) | list }}"
```

How can I handle this, for example, with nested loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test it first, for example

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "Create /data/{{ item.0.key }}/{{ item.1 }}"
      with_nested:
        - "{{ ftp|dict2items }}"
        - [in, out]
      when: item.0.value.state|d('present') == 'present'
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: Create /data/test/in
  msg: Create /data/test/out
  msg: Create /data/test2/in
  msg: Create /data/test2/out
```

Then try to create the dictionaries

```yaml
    - file:
        owner: "{{ item.0.key }}"
        group: ftp
        mode: '0755'  
        path: "/data/{{ item.0.key }}/{{ item.1 }}"
        state: directory
      with_nested:
        - "{{ ftp|dict2items }}"
        - [in, out]
      when: item.0.value.state|d('present') == 'present'
```

<sup>(not tested)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`product` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#products) to generate every possible combination of user/folder.

```yaml
loop: "{{ ftp.keys() | product(['in', 'out']) }}"
```

Then, respectively,

- `item.0` contains the users dictionary keys
- `item.1` contains the folders

It is not fully clear what your condition `when` does actually, in order to adapt it too, but I guess that you do have an `absent` or `present` state in those use dictionaries.

So, the resulting task should be something along the lines of

```yaml
- name: Create required folders
  ansible.builtin.file:
    owner: "{{ item.0 }}"
    group: ftp
    mode: '0755'
    path: "/data/{{ item.0 }}/{{ item.1 }}"
    state: directory
  loop: "{{ ftp.keys() | product(['in', 'out']) }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "/data/{{ item.0 }}/{{ item.1 }}"
  when: "ftp[item.0].state | default('absent') == 'present'"
  become: true
```

---

Given the task above, when run on those data:

```yaml
ftp:
  test:
    state: present
  test1:
  test2:
    state: present
```

It will yield:

```
TASK [Create required folders] ***************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=/data/test/in)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/data/test/out)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=/data/test1/in) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=/data/test1/out) 
ok: [localhost] => (item=/data/test2/in)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/data/test2/out)
```

Comment: Yes thats right, i use an absent and present state do delete old users.
When i try to build the role with your settings, i get an error message:

"msg": "Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list, got this instead: <itertools.product object at 0x7f1e78c7f640>. Hint: If you passed a list/dict of just one element, try adding wantlist=True to your lookup invocation or use q/query instead of lookup."
}

I think i need also this part in the loop:

"{{ query('dict', ftp) | list }}

Comment: Ok i installed a newer ansible version: ansible [core 2.12.5] and now it works! Thank you very much for the help!